# Blender UI button creation

Tags: python, customization

I have made a script which I wanna activate with that M button. I've seen tutorials on how to do the simple buttons but I can't seem to figure it out how to make a button there and how to add an icon to it.

[image: My UI design for the button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a way to modify existing UI elements once they're in a panel.

It also appears that the panel element for `DATA_PT_shape_keys` isn't exposed via `bpy.types` so I doubt the `.append()` trick will work.  But if somehow there is a way to extend it that's most likely where you'd find it.